# Python global is declared and yet I am getting an error that says its not present

Tags: python

This  has been asked many times on SO but I have some other bug which I am not seeing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from rosbook.msg import Detector

def scan_callback(msg):
    global closest
    global closest_dir
    closest_dir = ""
    closest = min(msg.forward, msg.left, msg.right, msg.back)
    if (msg.forward == closest):
        closest_dir = "forward"
    elif (msg.left == closets):
        closest_dir = "left"
    elif (msg.right == closest):
        closest_dir = "right"
    else:
        closest_dir = "back"


# Create a Publisher object. queue_size=1 means that messages that are
# published but not handled by received are lost beyond queue size.
cmd_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)
detect_sub = rospy.Subscriber('detector', Detector, scan_callback)

# Initialize this program as a node
rospy.init_node('pid_demo')

print (rospy.Time.now())
tw_for = Twist()
tw_for.linear.x = 0.3
tw_rot = Twist()
tw_for.angular.z = 0.5


# rate object gets a sleep() method which will sleep 1/10 seconds
rate = rospy.Rate(1)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    print (rospy.Time.now())
    if (closest_dir != "forward"):
        cmd_vel_pub.publish(tw_for)
    else:
        cmd_vel_pub.publish(tw_rot)
    rate.sleep()
```

Gives the error:

```
0
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pitosalas/catkin_ws/src/rosbook/scripts/pid_driver.py", line 42, in <module>
    if (closest_dir != "forward"):
NameError: global name 'closest_dir' is not defined
```

Those two 0's are interesting. It means that the while loop ran once before the callback was called and triggered the error. I've tried moving the global around, and changing the name but to me this looks totally valid!

Answer (score 0):

Just define variables `closest` and `closest_dir` outside of the method `scan_callback`. Hopeful you wont see the traceback

```
closest_dir = None
closest = None

def scan_callback(msg): ...
```

Comment: Do you still see same traceback?

Comment: One of the Python gotchas is that you need to use the keyword `global` if you are trying to set the value of a global inside a function, otherwise it will create a local variable - so I think you need to declare the variables as a global inside the function if you move them outside.